# Как вывести время начала дня в миллисекундах

Tags: java, android

я столкнулся с такой проблемой когда мне нужно получить время в миллисекундах на начало дня, то есть я создаю DataPikerDialog и выбираю конкретную дату, к примеру выбрано Mon, 04 Nov 2019 и время по дефолту 00:00:00 GMT в теории в логах должно появится следующее число 1572825600, однако логи выдают мне  следующее значение 1572886800 равное Mon, 04 Nov 2019 17:00:00 GMT, подскажите пожалуйста как мне выставить время по умолчанию 00:00:00 не используя при этом Time PikerDialog чтобы в логах выводилось время в миллисекундах выбранной даты с временем 00:00:00
вот пример моего кода, буду признателен за любую помощь.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    String TAG = "my";
    EditText editText;
    Calendar date = Calendar.getInstance();


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        editText = findViewById(R.id.editText);        

    }
     public void onClick(View view) {
        showDateTimePicker(view);
       // Log.d(TAG, "date +" + date);
    }

    // установка начальной даты
    private void setInitialDate() {
        editText.setText(DateUtils.formatDateTime(this,
                date.getTimeInMillis(),
                DateUtils.FORMAT_SHOW_DATE | DateUtils.FORMAT_SHOW_YEAR
        ));
    }

   public void showDateTimePicker(View view) { // выбор даты
       new DatePickerDialog(MainActivity.this, d,
               date.get(Calendar.YEAR),
               date.get(Calendar.MONTH),
               date.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)).show();
   }

   // установка обработчика даты
   DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener d = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
       @Override
       public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int dayOfMonth) {
           date.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
           date.set(Calendar.MONTH, month);
           date.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, dayOfMonth);
           //setInitialDate();
           date.set(Calendar.HOUR, 0);
           date.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
           date.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
           date.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);

           long beforeMidnight = (date.getTimeInMillis() - System.currentTimeMillis());
           Log.d(TAG, "date " + date);
           Log.d(TAG, "date.getTimeInMillis " + date.getTimeInMillis());
           Log.d(TAG, "System.currentTimeMillis " + System.currentTimeMillis());
           Log.d(TAG, "beforeMidnight " + beforeMidnight);
       }

   };
}
```

Comment: Часовой пояс какой?

Comment: @Эникейщик А это имеет значение? я бы хотел чтобы исправно работало в любом часовом поясе)

Comment: Да. Потому что по дефолту у вас время 0:00:00 не GMT, а вашего часового пояса (ну или того, который стоит в настройках системы), поэтому вам нужно явно задать GMT.

Comment: @Эникейщик подскажите пожалуйста как можно это сделать?

Comment: А вы уверены что понимаете что вы делаете? Время начала дня в Москве, Владивостоке и Нью-Йорке вообще-то очень разное.

Comment: @Alexey Ten мне нужно получить время начала дня в миллисекундах, получается что в зависимости от часового пояса. Есть какой нибудь унифицированный способ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1572886800 - число миллисекунд, прошедших с 1.01.1970 в часовом поясе +0 по текущий момент. Для меня с моим +7 часовым поясом это 5.11.19 00:00:00. Для того, кто живет в +0 это же значение приведется как 4.11.19 17:00:00. То есть все вы делаете правильно, просто проверяли в конвенторе, который указал вам время для +0. Определитесь в каком часовом поясе у вас должно быть точное начало дня и все будет ок.

Лайфхак - если вам нужно начало дня для +0 - возьмите текущее и вычтите остаток от деления на 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000 (время начала дня в миллисекундах для +0 кратно числу миллисекунд в дне). Если вам нужно для +4 - то делаем то же самое, просто в конце вычитаем 4 * 60 * 60 * 1000, получаем время начала дня для +4

Answer (score 0):

вся проблема была в параметре  date.set(Calendar.HOUR, 0); Calendar.HOUR использует 0-11 (для использования с AM / PM) и Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY0-23.
изменив данную строку на date.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0); время стало корректно отображаться. В данном же случае date.set(Calendar.HOUR, 0); отсчет времени начинался либо с полуночи либо с полудня в зависимости от текущего времени.